# Can't install doctrine/mongodb-odm using Composer

Tags: php, mongodb, composer-php, doctrine-odm, doctrine-mongodb

Trying to install doctrine/mongodb-odm via Composer I get this:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - doctrine/mongodb 1.0.x-dev requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.4-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb 1.0.2 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.4-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb 1.0.1 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.4-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb 1.0.0-BETA3 requires ext-mongo >=1.3.1,<1.4-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb 1.0.0-BETA2 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.3-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb 1.0.0-BETA1 requires ext-mongo * -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb 1.0.0 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.4-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for doctrine/mongodb 1.0.*@dev -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb 1.0.0, doctrine/mongodb 1.0.0-BETA1, doctrine/mongodb 1.0.0-BETA2, doctrine/mongodb 1.0.0-BETA3, doctrine/mongodb 1.0.1, doctrine/mongodb 1.0.2, doctrine/mongodb 1.0.x-dev.
```

However `php -m` has:

```
[PHP Modules]
...
mongo
...
```

And `composer.phar show --platform` has:

```
...
ext-mongo        1.3.5     The mongo PHP extension
...
```

Any ideas? The extension is definitely installed correctly, and Composer even lists it. The version (>=1.2.12,<1.4-dev) meets the requirements as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was the fault of the Sublime Text 2 Composer plugin. If I run Coomposer via Terminal it's fine. Why it doesn't work in ST2 is a bit of a mystery though, as far as I can tell it's executing exactly the same command: `/bin/composer.phar update -n -v`.

Comment: This might be because ST uses the Apache2 php.ini, and your CLI uses the CLI php.ini, and they could have different modules configured.

Answer (score 0):

If you loaded Mongo into an instance of PHP installed via WAMPSERVER, a likely cause for this issue is that only one of the 2 php.ini files was modified `path\to\wamp\bin\php\php5\php.ini`.  If you add the `extension=php_mongo.dll` to the `path\to\wamp\bin\apache\apche2\bin\php.ini` you should be able to execute php with mongo functions from the command line or editer cli tools.

If you run into composer error:

```
doctrine/mongodb 1.0.x-dev requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.5-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system
```

then it's another indicator you need to update the `apache2x\bin\php.ini` file